# Access Certain Variables in Columns

Tags: r

I solveed these 2 questions:

Q1= How many customers bought the new title “Art History of Florence”?

## improt Data

CBC.df = read.cvs(Datat File location)

```
Purchases=sum(CBC.df$Florence)
Purchases
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJHsd.png)

Q2: Out of those who bought “Art History of Florence”, what was the gender majority?

```
Purch.rows= which(CBC.df$Florence==1)
Females = sum(CBC.df[Purch.rows,3])
Females
Males = Purchases - Females 
Males
```

My question is: I tried to solve this question without using "Which" build in function in R. Is there any other way to select only female gender from the column without using Which? See the attached picture for details. Only focus on Gender and Florence we need.

Female = 1, male = 0

Your help or advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: Try `aggregate(Florence ~ Gender, CBC.df, sum)`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that the solution you currently have isn't working?

There is another convention that people commonly use from the dplyr (might need to be installed seperately) library where you can do the following:

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>% filter(Florence == 1, Gender == 1)
```